# I encounter an error after a flutter update. AssetManifest imported from two libraries

Tags: flutter, android-studio, google-fonts

I have an app that I created a year ago that worked great. Lately I opened my code and Flutter suggested I do an update. After the update it no longer works. the error encountered indicates that I imported AssetManifest from `'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart'` and from `'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'`.

> Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
> Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
> ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:14:1:
> Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both
> 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and
> 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'. import
> 'asset_manifest.dart'; ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/google_fonts-3.0.1/lib/src/google_fonts_base.dart:34:31:
> Error: 'AssetManifest' is imported from both
> 'package:flutter/src/services/asset_manifest.dart' and
> 'package:google_fonts/src/asset_manifest.dart'. AssetManifest
> assetManifest = AssetManifest();
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script '/Users/innot/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy'
>   line: 1214
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command '/Users/innot/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 7s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1

Comment: I suggest you upgrade the plugin to latest `google_fonts: ^5.1.0`, run flutter pub get and see if it helps or not.

Comment: Thank you. I add google_fonts 4.0.1 et make a change to auth_buttons: ^1.0.1+4 and it work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/material-foundation/flutter-packages/issues/403#issuecomment-1553291383), version `4.0.1` of the `google_fonts` fixes this issue. Therefore, upgrading to at least version `4.0.1` should resolve your problem.

Comment: Thank you. I add google_fonts 4.0.1 et make a change to auth_buttons: ^1.0.1+4 and it work.